# How do I make an extension of qobject cross platform

Tags: qt, cross-platform, qt-creator

I'm making a way of getting truly global hotkeys (I.e. emits a signal on certain inputs even when app is out of focus)

This will require different code for win vs osx vs x11. In qt creator how should I go about making this suitable for cross platform development.

Edit: I don't want to know how to do the actual code with x11, windows etc. I just want to know how I would do separate definitions for each platform.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to know how to do the actual code with x11, windows etc.
>   I just want to know how I would do separate definitions for each
>   platform.

It is convenient to do with ifdefs based on pre-defined compiler symbols e.g.:

http://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/OperatingSystems/

```
#ifdef __linux__   // linux related, GCC has that macros
   // your code and/or definitions
#endif

#if defined(__linux__) || defined(macintosh)
   // your code and/or definitions
#endif
```

You may use OR logic there as well, as many things on Mac resemble Linux and vise versa. Mind the compiler, though, if it has that symbol. I would use OR logic with all platform symbols of applicable compilers.

Comment: Would it look something like this??
#ifdef __linux__   
   // Linux compatible code
#endif

#ifdef macintosh
   // Mac compatible code
#endif     etc etc

Comment: Yes. A bit unsure of X11 as long as it is not an OS but GUI subsystem for Linux. If you really need to recognize than its symbol should be used as well e.g. X11.

Comment: I'll look into that but for my purposes right now I'm safe assuming the Linux systems are running x11. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use Qt, it has OS and compiler defines easily available for you:

```
#include <QtGlobal>

#if defined(Q_OS_LINUX)
// linux-specifc
#elif defined(Q_OS_WIN32) && defined(Q_CC_MSVC)
// win32 and msvc
#endif
```

[Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html).